VOIP Error Can't Connect, No Response from server
So this is for my high school project, and I just learning Ubuntu and want to make a VoIP call from one phone to another, but when connecting it says no response from server.
I tried following the instruction in this link , i also changed the ip address in the script to my ip address. I check my ip address using ip address show and use the 2nd one, because people often using that.
Can some one tell me how to solve this, or maybe my problem is not that detail, or maybe show me what should i differ from the video/

sudo asterisk -rx 'sip show peers'

sudo asterisk -rvvvx "sip show channels"

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
